# CFormView cleanup when switching Views

Tags: c++, mfc

Where is the best place to cleanup Gdi objects in a CFormView?

I have tried in CFormView::OnDestroy but it does not get called when switching views.

```
void CMyView::OnDestroy()
{
    CFormView::OnDestroy();

    if (m_brush.m_hObject!=NULL)
        VERIFY(m_brush.DeleteObject());
}
```

The problem is that I have many gdi objects created in OnInitialUpdate which are created everytime a user activates the view. So I need a better method of cleaning the gdi objects when the user switches the views.

Comment: Maybe the object isn't destroyed when the user switches the views?

Comment: no, only when the application is closed.

Comment: Why do you unconditionally create GDI objects, whenever a view is activated? Fix that bug, and you won't need a workaround.

Comment: because I have over 30 views and there are many bitmaps, fonts and brushes and they take a lot of RAM to create them in the constructor and leave them in memory until the app is closed.

Comment: The question was, why you create those objects **unconditionally**. Apart from that, RAM is not ever a limit you're likely to hit. It's rather *address space*, or *desktop heap* in case of GDI objects. If you don't understand memory management, you won't be able to reliably predict performance characteristics. Your assumptions are wrong, and will lead to invalid conclusions.

Comment: If you are programming that way...that the RAM is never a limit then you will never be able to create large scale applications. I prefer to cleanup the memory when the form views are switched or else new gdi objects will be created and will slow down everything.

Comment: Would you mind **comprehending** prior to responding? Available RAM is not ever a limit you're **likely to hit**. Even if you tried, you'd hit a number of other limits prior to that (desktop heap, for example, as pointed out already). In case you care to educate yourself, here's a primer: [Memory Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366779.aspx). Also, unused GDI objects do not slow down anything. They merely occupy resources that cannot otherwise be used. And that's it.

Comment: Bitmaps use global memory and not desktop heap, in case of my app at every view change the app. Is using 10MB more memory, that is 1GB at 100 views cahnged.

Comment: Which brings us full circle to my initial question: Why do you **unconditionally** (this isn't emphasized for sports) create GDI objects? Your application leaks resources. Fix that bug and you won't need a workaround. Am I the only one having a déjà vu?

Comment: Ok I will create them conditionally